# no ping during routing

Tags: networking, route

I have a computer A (190.21.8...) and B (190.21.5....) and C(222.104.100....)
I can mstsc from A to B, and also - I have ping from A to C, and from A to B,
but not from B to C?

How can this be fixed? For example, is it possible to add a route that will make B contact A and from there to C?

**Note:** forgot to mention - all pc computers

Comment: Is it possible that ICMP echo (ping) is blocked on the 190.21.5.* network? Also, is this for some household or small biz setup? If so, you need to use IP addresses in a range that you control -- or in one of the many private address blocks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want B to contact C or is this design intent? If not you could add route to C on B and route to B on C and make them ping each other directly.

Comment: This questions doesn't have anywhere near enough details to give a reasonable answer; there plenty of reasons this might be broke. The questioner is obviously not a system administrator. Thanks SO for another steaming shovel full.

Comment: @Chris S, I agree that this question doesn't have enough details, but that is not a sufficient condition to say it's unsalvagable; all you have to do is ask clarifying questions: we do this all day long on StackOverflow.  The real problem here is that we have no way to communicate with @ComputeALot after the question has been migrated.  I'm submitting to Meta as a case to see what should be done.

Comment: @Mike, "the real problem here is that" ComputeALot is *not a System Administrator*, as per the requirements stated in [SF's FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) this question **should not have been migrated here**. I know SO doesn't require prerequisite knowledge in the topic of the question, but *this isn't SO, it's SF*; thank you for appreciating the difference. User question related to a Windows environment (or "pc computers" as this user thinks all PCs inherently run Windows) should be migrated to SU; if it was related to a *nix environment unix.SE (probably) would have been a better fit.

Comment: @Chris S, the FAQ includes "people who support or maintain computers in a professional capacity".  How likely is it that an amateur is using `mstsc`?  Saying all computers are "PC" computers is easily explained by someone who may not be a native english-speaker.  If you feel that passionately the question should go to SU, then vote to migrate, but as someone who has been in IT for the last 15 years, I don't see this as a glaring case of "some lowly user asking an out-of-place question on SF"

Comment: I didn't feel passionately about the question and still don't (my apologies if I'm coming across in a harsh/impassioned tone); I'm just pointing out the obvious; that and SO mis-migrates to SF about once or twice a week. You can't vote to re-migrate a question. Once SO has put it on us, we have to get a mod involved to move it to the correct site; Or if we think the OP is unlikely to return to fill in the details, we just close it as NARQ (ComputeALot is highly unlikely to add the relevant details to make this 'question' answerable).

Comment: It isn't our place to manage questions based on what *we think* the OP will do in the future.  I agree that we may never see him again, but that's when you close it as NARQ.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the exact error would be helpful to debug this problem.  Also this seems more like a sysadmin problem (superuser?).  In any case, running traceroute would also help debug this problem.

But assuming that there is some administrative blocking of B->C, it is technically possible to go through A.  It isn't a route, instead you need to create a tunnel (such as openvpn, or ipip, or any number of other tunnels) between B and A, then on A you would (typically) NAT or MASQUERADE B's IP address to A or some IP address assigned to A.  C then is not aware of B's IP address.  Packets travel from A to B through the tunnel (source B, destination C), B then rewrite the packet to, etc from A to C.  C replies to B, B rewrite again from C to B, packet travels over tunnel.